# Tridion 2009 - Using Interops on Custom page - User should acts as something like admin

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

I have a clarification related to handling of user access on custom page using Interops dlls.

Below is the scenario:-

1. `ABC user` doesn't have any sort of access on `CM`  (Note: ABC user is a tridion user)
2. If ABC user access the custom page, user should get impersonate with admin user
3. Now ABC user will create/update the components/pages and publish the components/pages
4. But the problem is on history of components/pages shows the name of `admin user` name but I want to record the changes with the name of `ABC user`

> How can I achieve this?
>   **OR**
>   Without using impersonation, Is there any best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

I am wondering why you want to do this. When you are impersonating user ABC with an Admin user, the ABC user can do anything in the system.

Why don't you add the ABC user to CM system and give the user required rights and permissions.

To record the changes with the name of ABC user in the history the user needs to be a CM User as far as I know.

Comment: ABC user is a tridion user but this user doesn't have any sort of access. I can't give required access since that is the criteria. So without giving any access to the ABC user, he should perform all required action through the custom page. How can I achieve this and also on history ABC user name should be there?

Comment: If we impersonate with Admin user, changes are recorded in the name of Admin user only not in the name of ABC user.

Comment: "since that is the criteria" is not a reason. What is the reason that you can't give the person access? Is this a homework question?

Comment: You can create shadow accounts for each ABC user with required rights and permission. Store the link between ABC user and its shadow account. Use that shadow account for ABC user to create/update items in Tridion.

Comment: @DominicCronin: The actual reason behind not giving access to the ABC user, since these users will update only specific content through this custom page. And also business don't want these user to access the Content manager to update this content because they can misuse of the CM. So am thinking the best way to achieve this situation.

Comment: Then give them only access to the things they should be able to see/modify. If you are doing this through a custom page, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @DominicCronin: You mean giving access only to the specific folders & structure groups where am doing the changes. Right?

Comment: Yes. The user can just use their own identity.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure what you are trying to do is impossible as suggested by @Bappi. You have 2 choices when performing an action on a Tridion Item. Either do it as someone with rights to perform the action OR impersonate as a user who does have the rights (i.e. your admin user). The CMS will store system metadata about which user performed the action (thisis the user you see who created or modified the Component). This data can not (and should not) be overwritten or modified using the APIs.

If you really need to know who performed the action, either give them the rights to do so (It seems like an odd requirement when you are giving them this security loop hole anyway, perhaps you can explain more about the logic behind this), or maybe add a field to your schema called "Author" and use your Custom Page to populate it with the username of ABC.

If that is not a viable option, you may also consider giving user ABC access to some kind of temporary folder in the target Publication where they can make the Component under their own account (still through the Custom Page) so you get the history, and then impersonate the Admin user to move it to the desired location.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the permissions to the publication level on fly?

1. On load of custom page, set the permission to the user to the specific publications.
2. On completion of action, remove the permission from the user.

But I guess, still there is a loop hole.

While this custom page is running, if user access the Content Manager they can see the publications and they can perform required actions at that moment.